# IntelliJ Shortcut to force maven reimport

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Does IntelliJ IDEA have a short-cut to force maven project reimport (to reload dependencies). I happen to be working with two dependant projects and I make that action many times during the day.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your own key map in IDE Settings. To do it :

- Menu *File* > *Settings*
- Under *IDE Settings*, choose *Keymap*
- Expand the tree to *Plug-ins* > *Maven integration*
- You normally see "Reimport All Maven Projects"
- Right-click on this item and choose a Key or Mouse shortcut.

(I did this with IDEA EAP 12, under windows)

Answer (score 3):

I looked throught keymap reference(`Help->Dafault Keymap Reference`) and didn't find anything with maven. But when I make some changes in my `pom.xml` IDEA shows dialog in which it offer to import all dependencies.

other maven settings you can find in `File->Settings->Maven->Import` or use combination `Shift+CTRL+A` and in input field write maven.

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of Intellij and macos, hit shift-shift and then type "reload maven" to get to the "Reload All Maven Projects" action. This will refresh the dependencies - no need to reimport.